# Why Django REST Framework (DRF) folder structure is different than Django Turorial?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If you follow the Django Tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) you'll run theses commands:

```sh
django-admin startproject mysite
# Change into the outer mysite directory
cd mysite
python manage.py startapp polls
```

and you'll get this folder structure

```
mysite/
├── manage.py
│
├── mysite/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
│
└── pools/
    ├── migrations/
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── admin.py
    ├── apps.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

But if you follow Django REST Framework [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and you'll run these commands:

*Note: I replaced the directory names to match, for better comparison*

```sh
# Create the project directory
mkdir mysite
cd mysite
# Set up a new project with a single application
django-admin startproject mysite .  # Note the trailing '.' character
cd mysite
django-admin startapp polls
cd ..
```

and you'll get this folder structure

```
mysite/
├── manage.py
│
└── mysite/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── asgi.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    ├── wsgi.py
    │
    └── polls/
        ├── migrations/
        │   └── __init__.py
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── admin.py
        ├── apps.py
        ├── models.py
        ├── tests.py
        └── views.py
```

This is DFR's explanation:

> It may look unusual that the application has been created within the project directory. Using the project's namespace avoids name clashes with external modules (a topic that goes outside the scope of the quickstart).

What I want to know is more about this "topic that goes outside the scope of the quickstart". I would like to read up on more of this topic and have some examples. Also why does Django Tutorial teaches something that "apparently" has problems and "apparently" you shouldn't do.

Comment: You should not `cd` to the `mysite` app.

Comment: Because you ran the `django-admin startapp` command in different directories in each example - in the first one you ran it in `mysite/`, in the second in `mysite/mysite/`.

Comment: I only did what both tutorials told me to do. This in on their websites I didn't decide what commands to run.

Comment: I think it is better to use python manage.py startapp <yourappname> command. It will not allow to create new app folder in your project folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you follow the Django REST framework tutorial, you will indeed end up with the directory you describe. In [the documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/#project-setup) we see that the file structure looks like:

```
.
./manage.py
./tutorial
./tutorial/__init__.py
./tutorial/quickstart
./tutorial/quickstart/__init__.py
./tutorial/quickstart/admin.py
./tutorial/quickstart/apps.py
./tutorial/quickstart/migrations
./tutorial/quickstart/migrations/__init__.py
./tutorial/quickstart/models.py
./tutorial/quickstart/tests.py
./tutorial/quickstart/views.py
./tutorial/settings.py
./tutorial/urls.py
./tutorial/wsgi.py
```

If we put that in a tree structure, we see:

```
.
├── manage.py
└── tutorial
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── quickstart
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   └── __init__.py
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

But this is *not* the same code structure that the [Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/) use, in that case we create the project structure with:

```
# Create the project directory
mkdir mysite
cd mysite

# Set up a new project with a single application
django-admin startproject mysite .
#  no cd mysite
django-admin startapp polls
cd ..
```

then the project directory looks like:

```
.
./manage.py
./tutorial
./tutorial/__init__.py
./quickstart
./quickstart/__init__.py
./quickstart/admin.py
./quickstart/apps.py
./quickstart/migrations
./quickstart/migrations/__init__.py
./quickstart/models.py
./quickstart/tests.py
./quickstart/views.py
./tutorial/settings.py
./tutorial/urls.py
./tutorial/wsgi.py
```

or thus as a filetree:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── quickstart
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
└── tutorial
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── settings.py
    ├── urls.py
    └── wsgi.py
```

You thus call `django-admin startapp polls` in the *root* directory, so the *outer* `mysite` directory, not the <s>*inner* `mysite`</s>.

The reason that the Django REST framework advices this extra layer is to avoid name clashes. If you for example would like to name an app `zipfile`, then this clashes with the module of the [**`zipfile`** package [Python-docs]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), so then your modules can no longer reference items of the `zipfile` package.

By nesting these in the project name, you thus will makes these modules available as `from nameofawesomeproject.zipfile`, and thus you can still `import zipfile` for the package.

The app labels however do *not* change automatically: the name of the app is by default the name of the deepest nested module name, so for `django.contrib.auth`, it is `auth`. You can set a different name by implementing an [**`AppConfig`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#application-configuration) for your project.

Comment: This in not what I've decided to do, this is what the tutorials say you should do. All I want to know is the reasons why DRF and Django Tutorial disagree

Comment: @Unstable: can you share *where* you found these scripts.

Comment: If these are a concatenation of two items, then likely the context is that you should use `cd mysite` once, and thus the other shell script simply assumed that it was located back at the root path.

Comment: for django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/
for DRF: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/

Comment: @Unstable: the DRF documentation makes the filetree that you show, thus with `polls` inside `mysite`, whereas the Django tutorial makes it how you want toe file structure (so your first code fragment in the question). Both thus set up a slightly different project structure. I would advise to first learn the basics of Django, and then use DRF, since this is build on top of Django and requires some understanding about how Django works: DRF also works with models, has something different than forms (serializers), etc.

Comment: Both project trees can work, but it will require some changes on how to load, install and update the different apps of the project.

Comment: I understand all of that but my question is **why** do they do it in a different way and I would like to **have some examples** of the problems that DRF says it's trying to solve.

Comment: @Unstable: because often an API is embedded in the app itself. So the app structure looks differently, since the API can be seen as a "sub app" of the real app, in other words `polls` is a subapp` of the `mysite` app.

Comment: DRF states that the reason why they do it is that "Using the project's namespace avoids name clashes with external modules" this is what I'm interested in knowing about. I want to **know more about this topic** and **examples**.

Comment: @Unstable: it usually means that if you want to write an app named `zipfile`, then you can not use the [**`zipfile`** library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html). Therefore if you create a module named `myawesomeproject.zipfile` as project name, it will still make it possible to import `zipfile`. But in general it is a bad idea to give an app a name that clashes with a (popular) library, since it makes it less predictable what the project is.

Comment: @Unstable: You need to specify the name in the `AppConfig`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/ . For default app labels it indeed does nothing, for imports however it does something: while the app label is `auth`, the module is `from django.contrib.auth.models import User` for example. This is also where the clashes will happen for imports.

Comment: Yup this last two comments were the answer I was looking for, I understand now. If you change your answer to this I'll be happy to approve this.